# Fresh install of wordpress redirects to local address when I try to access the site

Tags: wordpress, apache

The domain points to my organisation web-server
links like _http://domain/post123 works fine
But when I try to access http://domain - it redirects me to my local address
Also link on web-site have a look like: _http://localaddress/post123

I have no idea how to fix it and will be greatful for any help

Comment: Have you checked your config or db to ensure the site URL has been updated?

Comment: Thats the wp_options table and the siteurl and home options.

Comment: I have a correct siteurl in wp_options, I even can visit site by entering domainname, but internal link on pages have format localaddress/articlepage
also, when I try to access wp-admin, I can access login page, but after I enter credentionals, it redirects me to local url of wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

Go to PHPMYADMIN. Select your database and select options table(someprefix_options). There check home values.

Refer this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL